# Why must I send the CSRF token with AFNetworking but not with cURL?

Tags: django-rest-framework, afnetworking, afnetworking-3

When I perform a POST request via cURL, it completes successfully (HTTP 201) even  without sending the CSRF token header.

```
curl -X POST http://server/app/addrecord/ -d '{"pk":"1", "lname":"Smith", "fname":"Robert"}' -H "Content-Type: application/json" > out.html
```

However when I attempt the same operation using AFNetworking in Obj-C, I get a 403 error that states the CSRF token is required.

```
AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];

AFJSONRequestSerializer *serializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];
[serializer setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[serializer setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
[manager setRequestSerializer:serializer];

AFJSONResponseSerializer *respSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
respSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObjects:@"application/json", @"text/html", @"text/plain", @"text/json", nil];
manager.responseSerializer = respSerializer;

[manager POST:@"http://server/app/addrecord/" parameters:parameters success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *  task, id   responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"Success");
} failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *  task, NSError *  error) {
    NSLog(@"Error");
}];
```

Simply by adding the following line to my request serializer, the error goes away.

```
[serializer setValue:csrf forHTTPHeaderField:@"X-CSRFTOKEN"];
```

While I don't need the AFNetworking code to work without the CSRF Token being sent, I would like to understand why the cURL command works without the token but the AFNetworking code doesn't.

Comment: Same problem here. Any news on that topic?